# streaming pointcloud to remote workstation

Tags: ros, image-pipeline, pointcloud

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I am trying to use pointcloud generated by a robot on remote workstation. However, I figured that susbscribing pointcloud2 is eating too much bandwidth.

Could anybody teach me what is the best way to get pointcloud data from a robot and use it on the remote workstation?

My current idea is instead of subscribing pointcloud2 data directly, setting up compressed version of pointcloud_xyzrgb image_pipeline on the remote workstation and re-produce pointcloud2 data.

Thanks,
Jihoon

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/64870/streaming-pointcloud-to-remote-workstation/) by [jihoonl](https://answers.ros.org/users/830/jihoonl/) on ROS Answers with karma: 634 on 2013-06-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In our setup, we've split the `openni_launch`-launch-file into two separate launch-files:

- The one running on the machine which is connected to the kinect (in your case: on the robot) only loads the driver and publishes raw images and the tf-data
- On a remote machine, image_proc is launched which calculates and publishes the actual point clouds

This way, only the raw 2d data (`depth/image_raw`, `rgb/image_raw`) is transmitted over the network.

---

Originally posted by [Philip](https://answers.ros.org/users/4292/philip/) with karma: 990 on 2013-06-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jihoonl](https://answers.ros.org/users/830/jihoonl/) on 2013-06-11**:
Looks good thanks! Have you tried compressed image_transport too?

**Comment by [Ben_S](https://answers.ros.org/users/1072/ben_s/) on 2013-06-12**:
Would it be possible to post your splitted launch files? Thanks! :)

**Comment by [jihoonl](https://answers.ros.org/users/830/jihoonl/) on 2013-06-12**:
I have similar but a little different launch file created for turtlebot pointcloud streaming. Please refer this.https://gist.github.com/jihoonl/5770238